# Regenerate Snapshots from .avhdx files

Tags: backup, hyper-v, snapshot

I'm getting used to **Hyper-V** and I come into this situation:

I manually did a backup and a restore of a virtual machine with **1 disk** and **2 snapshots**. My restored machine has **a .vhdx** file and **2 .avhdx** files and it works well.

Sadly, I **can't see** my 2 snapshot in the *Hyper-V Management Console* snapshot list. Even if I can't see those 2 snapshot Hyper-V uses all my 3 disk files (the .vhdx and the 2 .avhdx) giving me the latest updated disk state.

Can I **regenerate** those 2 snapshot into the list? I saw every snapshot has a .xml file, its possible to regenerate those files?

Answer (score 1):

When you create a VM that points to an AVHDX file and that file has no associated snapshot, Hyper-V will immediately merge-away that AVHDX.  I suspect that you'll find that you already have only one AVHDX file, the one that the VM points to.  You may already have no AVHDX files.

If you want to restore snapshots along with the VM, you have to do so by backing up the VM (and its snapshots) with software that will pay attention to those snapshots and recreate them on restore.  This will be true of almost any backup application, like Windows Server Backup, or Data Protection Manager, or anything else, really.

You can even manually export a VM and then archive the exported VM, importing it later when you want to restore it.  (A configuration-only export will avoid copying the VHDs, but if you can point the export operation directly at your backup media, you'll only be copying them once.)

What you can't successfully do is just save the VHDs and easily recreate a new VM later that is equivalent (even in snapshots) to the one you had before.  A VM is more (though only a little more) than the sum of its VHDs.

Comment: i'll take this answer as a "no, you can't do that" :) Thank you!